# PHP array with variable in it

Tags: php

I just got some really strange problem.

Check it out:

```
$yourWord='http://mywebsite.com/combo-points-carmaboy-boys-sixer';
$URLW = "'kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six'";
$targets = array($URLW);


$pattern = '/\b('.implode('|', $targets).')\b/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $yourWord, $matches)) {
echo 'FOUND!!';
} else {
echo 'NOT FOUND!';
}
```

In this way it's giving me result `NOT FOUND!` but when i do that
`$targets = array('kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six');` it's working.

So why it's not working on the way i make it in my code sample ?

And how i can use it with variable in the array ?

Thanks

Comment: $URLW is a string, it wont get evaluated into an array structure because it looks like one.

Comment: PHP users are so used to evaluate strings to whatever type or construction they want, that they forget how the programming really works...

Answer (score 2):

`$targets = array("'kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six'");`

is a an array consisting of a single element that's a comma separated string

`$targets = array('kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six');`

is an array consisting of 4 string elements

Answer (score 1):

To explain why it's not found, `array($URLW)` returns an array with ONE element, as it's ONE string containing commas. This makes `implode()` return false (as it expects the first argument to be an array, and not a string), and your statement completely different than you expected (instead it should convert the value `int(0)` into a string in the regex-pattern within the word-boundaries, which isn't what you want, and which doesn't exist in your pattern). If you need to use the string with commas, split it first using `explode()`, then keep that array:

```
$URLW = explode(", ", "'kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six'");
```

If you don't need to use it, then simply declare the array with the regular syntax:

```
$URLW = Array("kid", "kids", "boys", "six");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi whats this all about?

```
$URLW = "'kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six'";
$targets = array($URLW);
```

Try like this

```
 $targets = array('kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six');
```

Here is your regx before changing it, by the way.

```
 /\b('kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six')\b
```

Here is the regx you wanted,

```
 /\b(kid|kids|boys|six)\b
```

And if you need this bit   `$URLW` as a string

```
 $URLW = "'".implode("', '", $targets )."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$URLW` is a string, `array()` won't be able to convert the comma separated items to expected array format. You either need to initialize the array properly:

```
$targets = ('kid', 'kids', 'boys', 'six');
```

Or convert the string to an array using something like this:

```
$targets = array_map(function($target) {
  return trim($target, "' ");
}, explode(',', $URLW));
```